# How can I align captions to the right side of an image in JSSOR?

Tags: slider, jssor

I have the slider all set up, and I want to have two captions: one should slide in from the left and stay on the left side of the image; the second one should slide in from the right and stay on the right side of the image. However, if I try changing the `left: 0` of the second caption to `right: 0` it breaks the slider. The image becomes all stretched and stops working.

Is there a way to stick the caption to the right side?

### Javascript

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.menu').dropit({
                action: 'mouseover'
            });
            action: 'hover';
            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            {$Duration:3000,$Opacity:2}
            ];

    var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 800, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 800, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 800, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 800, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["TL"] = { $Duration: 800, x: 0.6, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["TR"] = { $Duration: 800, x: -0.6, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["BL"] = { $Duration: 800, x: 0.6, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["BR"] = { $Duration: 800, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["WAVE|L"] = { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.6, y: 0.3, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Top: 2.5} };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|B"] = { $Duration: 600, $Clip: 8, $Move: true, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutExpo };

    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: true,
        $FillMode: 2,
        $SlideshowOptions: {
                $SlideWidth: 1920,
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                $ShowLink: true
            },

        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            },

        $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 0                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            }

    };
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
```

### HTML

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1920px; height: 1080px; margin: auto; overflow: hidden;">                
                    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1920px; height: 600px; margin: 0;">
                    <div style="float: right;">
                        <img u="image" src="images/slider03.jpg" />
                        <div u="caption" t="L" t2="NO" style="position: absolute; top: 450px; left: 0px; width: 350px; height: 40px; background-color: #ff6c00; color: white; font-size: 24px; text-align: right; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;"><a href="project.php" style="color: white;">Click to view project</a></div>
                        <div u="caption" t="R" t2="NO" style="position: absolute; top: 450px; right: 0px; width: 350px; height: 40px; background-color: #ff6c00; color: white; font-size: 24px; text-align: right; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;"><a href="project.php" style="color: white;">TREE HOUSES</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div><img u="image" src="images/slider01.jpg" /></div>
                    <div><img u="image" src="images/slider02.jpg" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For caption element, Jssor Slider recognizes 'top', 'left' instead of 'bottom', 'right'.

Please replace 'right: 0px' with 'left: 1570px' then.